# what is default username and passoword for busybox's ftpd

Tags: ftp, android, busybox

I am trying to ftp into my android device which is running ftpd server of busybox's multi-binary, 
 As the ftpd applet quotes "Anonymous ftp server" but when I use anonymous as username and my email address as password from my pc it says login failed ,
 So in this situation what is the way to authenticate.

Comment: Tye using just `anon`

Answer (score 1):

If you built it yourself, make sure authentication is disabled if you want anonymous connections. In `make menuconfig`,

```
Networking Utilities ->
    [*] ftpd
    [*]   Enable upload commands
    [*]   Enable workaround for RFC-violating clients
    [ ]   Enable authentication
```

If you downloaded it from somewhere, it may have authentication enabled. If it has the `bbconfig` applet you can also check the configuration to see if it has ftp authentication with `busybox bbconfig | busybox grep FTPD_AUTH`.

If you want it to work with authentication, you may have to add a user. From the source code it looks like it reads from the passwd and shadow files, so if you can add a user and specify the username and password for it then you should be able to login.

Answer (score -1):

For anonymous access you don't need to pass a username/password. Just connect in without issuing USER or PASS.

Comment: I've tried this it doesn't works either

Answer (score -2):

see the /etc/shadow or /etc/passwd (if the /etc/shadow not exist) with texteditor

or

cat /etc/passwd
cat /etc/shadow

if you use terminal.
It will show something like these:

root:$6$jc.8CPty$8rBE2WGgYuCH88ZSl0p8qohQqCBnvaBAy2fgUIq7vBL1Avv.0vCqZE/1k0X1gdZ62HEOvUBZNmXCluS0hsjd8/:10933:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:10933:0:99999:7:::

(not that lucky, you need to use john the ripper to brute force the password)
or

root::10933:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:10933:0:99999:7:::

(your lucky, all you have to do is to specify the user as root then set the password to anything, don't blank the password)

note: if after the username: shows *, it cannot be used to login, because it used

Comment: please provide me the busybox that you use, so i can test it. I've build my own busybox and what i say above is my own experience. And tell me the reason you gave me -1?